# Scope Problems, Sencha, Getting Data passed to view from controller in items?

Tags: extjs, scope, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am passing a record in from the controller via:

```
showDetail: function (list, record) {

    this.getMain().push({
        xtype: 'leaddetail',
        data: record.data
    });
},
```

My View:

```
Ext.define('ApexChat.view.LeadDetail', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
xtype: 'leaddetail',

init: function() {
    debugger;
},


config: {
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    title: 'Details',
    frame: true,
    labelwidth: 75,




    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        columnWidth: 0.5,
        collapsible: true,
        title: 'Lead Information',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        defaults: { anchor: '100%' },
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'name',
                tpl: '{name}',
                value: '{name}',
                disabled: true
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                name: 'email',
                value: '{email}',
                disabled: true
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Phone',
                name: 'phone',
                value: '{phone}',
                disabled: true
            }
        ]
       }, 
       {
           xtype: 'fieldset',
           columnWidth: 0.5,
           collapsible: true,
           title: 'Exta Information',
           defaultType: 'textfield',
           defaults: { anchor: '100%' },
           layout: 'vbox',
         items: [
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Company Key',
                name: 'companykey',
                value: '{companyKey}',
                disabled: true
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Chat ID',
                name: 'chatid',
                value: '{chatId}',
                disabled: true
            },
            {
                fieldtype: 'textarea',
                fieldLabel: 'Notes',
                name: 'notes',
                value: '{notes}',
                disabled: true
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}
});
```

But inside the textfields i still see {companyName}

Assuming it cant be done like that, so how do I access the record being passed from the controller so I can do a .get('name') or something similar to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tpl` and `data` are used for rendering custom HTML, while Ext fields are components that handle their own rendering. You shouldn't have to touch their `tpl`, except for advanced use cases.

As opposed to other frameworks that are mainly based on HTML templates, Ext is essentially a object oriented component library. You rarely go to the HTML level yourself.

For setting the values of a bunch of fields at once, you need to put them in a [`Ext.form.Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel). Then you can use [`setValues`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-setValues) or, maybe more appropriated in your case, [`setRecord`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-setRecord).

Using your example, you would configure your fields this way:

```
Ext.define('ApexChat.view.LeadDetail', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'leaddetail',

    config: {
        ...
        items: [{
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            // you only need the name for the field to load data
            name: 'name'
        },{
            fieldLabel: 'Email',
            name: 'email'
        }]
    }
});
```

Then you can assign your record at creation time using the [`record`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-record) config option:

```
this.getMain().push({
    xtype: 'leaddetail',
    // using record config option
    record: record
});
```

Or you can use the methods to load the data:

```
// get a ref to your component the way you want, this line just illustrates what's in formPanel
var formPanel = Ext.create({xtype: 'leaddetail'});

// using setValues
formPanel.setValues(record.data);

// or using setRecord
formPanel.setRecord(record);
```

Comment: I tried the top method, changed data: record.data to record: record but the data still does not load?

Comment: You `leaddetail` component must extend from `Ext.form.Panel`, and not from `Ext.Panel`. Furthermore, are you sure that `this.getMain().push` is really what you want? Shouldn't you call the  [`add`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Container-method-add) method instead?