# pass data from controller to existing view in sencha tocuh

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

i am trying to pass a data from controller to existing view , i have tried following but non of them are working , i want to pass a data so that i can show it over an existing panel.

from controller

```
1. Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem('profileinfo');
   Ext.Viewport.setData(record.data);

2. Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem('profileinfo').setData(record.data);

3. Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem('profileinfo', {data:record.data});

4. Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({ xtype:'profileinfo', data:record.data});
```

where `profileinfo` is the panel where there is a `titlebar` and i am displaying `title` as `{member_data}` which is part of data

```
loadList:function(me, index, target, record, e, eOpts){


        console.log(record.data.member_name);

            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({ 
                xtype:'profileinfo', 
                data:record.data}
            );



    }
```

i can see in my `profileinfo` panel's `initialize` function that `data` is available 
but i am not be able to access it using `{member_name}`

```
initialize: function(){
       this.callParent();

       console.log("initialized");
       console.log(this.config.data); // able to see the data 
    }
```

but data is not reflected in panel

```
  {

        xtype:'titlebar',
        title:'{member_name}' // its displaying {member_name} text rather then data itself


    }
```

**update**

here is the `profileinfo` code

```
 Ext.define('demo.view.ProfileInfo', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
        xtype: 'profileinfo',
        requires: [ 'Ext.TitleBar','demo.view.ProfileMemberInfo'],
        config: {


            layout:'vbox',


            items: [

            {
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'demo',
                cls: 'bms-bg-head',
                height:'65px',
                center:true,
                html:'<div class="demo-mini-logo"></div>'
            },{




                    xtype:'label',
                    // nothing is visible here
                    html:'{member_name}'



            }]
        },

        initialize: function(){
           this.callParent();

           //  record is visible
           console.log(this.config.record);





    }

});
```

here is controller code

```
loadList:function(me, index, target, record, e, eOpts){



            Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({ 
                xtype:'profileinfo', 
                record:record
                }
            );





    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said your getting data in panel's `initialize` method, So you can do this

```
initialize: function(){
       this.callParent();
       console.log("initialized");
       var data = this.config.data;
       this.down('titlebar').setTitle(data.member_data);
}
```

---

Based on your comments, You can set data to the panel you [setRecord](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-setRecord).

**Update**

Have a reference to the formPanel in your controller

```
config : {
        refs : {
            Profileinfo: 'profileinfo'
        }
    }
```

***In ProfileInfo view***

For selecting label i suggest you to give itemId to label like this

```
{ 
  xtype:'label',
   itemId: 'member'
}
```

**In your controller  loadList function**

If you have fields (textfield, selectfield, etc) inside formpanel,you can use `setValues()` for setting data as i done below.

But label is not a field so, you have to select it and then use `setHtml()` to set data

```
loadList:function(me, index, target, record, e, eOpts){

 Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({ xtype:'profileinfo'});

 this.getProfileinfo().setValues(record.getData());

 //As you posted in your question, I am assuming member label is child of Profileinfo
 this.getProfileinfo().getComponent('member').setHtml(record.getData().member_name)

}
```

**Most important**

Properties or fields in the `record` should match name of the fields in the frompanel, Then only `setValues()` works.

**Example**

If you have field like this in frompanel

```
 {
   xtype: 'textfield',
   label: 'First Name',
   name: 'Firstname'
 }
```

`record.getData()` should have `Firstname` property in it.

---

**Update for setting data in panel with tpl**

Lets say you have panel like this

```
Ext.define('MailApp.view.MessageDetails', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'messageDetails',   
    config: {
        items : [{
                 xtype: 'titlebar',
                 docked: 'top',
                 itemId: 'detailsTitle'
              },
            {
            xtype : 'panel',
            itemId : 'details',
            tpl : new Ext.Template(
            '<div class="details">',
            '<p>From : {from}</p>',
            '<p>Subject : {subject}</p>',
            '<p>Message : {message}</p>',                   
            </div>'
            )
        }]
    }
});
```

**In your controller  loadList function**

```
loadList:function(me, index, target, record, e, eOpts){
 var data = record.getData();

 Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem({ xtype:'messageDetails'});

 // Don't forget to put refference to work this.getMessageDetails()

 this.getMessageDetails().getComponent('details').setData(data);

 this.getMessageDetails().getComponent('detailsTitle').setHtml(data.detailsTitle)

}
```

**When you print console.log(record.data()) you should have**

```
Object {from: "Apple", subject: "welcome", message: "Apple welcomes you to mail app", detailsTitle: " Mail Deatils", id: "ext-record-1", xindex: 1}
```

I mean properties should match fields in the tpl.

This is what you can do to set data in panel's custom HTML using tpl.

Comment: is there anyway to set it using `{member_name}` because i have other components to set , even the code you have suggested is also not working

Comment: what you mean not working.. are you getting any error or it is setting undefined ?

Comment: yeah and its being displayed in console, but not inside a title

Comment: is console.log(this.down('titlebar')); printing titlebar object ?

Comment: yeah i guess i am having two titlebars and it was setting in the first one , what to do if i want to set it in the second one ? 

more over is there any way to set it data as `{member_name}` bcoz on a panel i have 10 new fields and its not proper to set it using only set methods

Comment: give itemId for second titlebar and select with this.getComponent(itemId).. use setRecord as i said in my answer for setting data in panel.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994322/scope-problems-sencha-getting-data-passed-to-view-from-controller-in-items)

Comment: the approach tht u suggested is following MVC pattern ? and the thing is i dont want to use Form at all , i want to display my own html frame as form has its own style and styling it again is big pain

Comment: Yes, it follows MVC and i always follow MVC in sencha touch. if you don't want form.. the create panel with tpl and put html in it then set data using setData() function from the controller, let me explain that in my answer..